# How to setup MATLAB diff and merge for Git on Mac OSX

Tags: git, macos, matlab

I'm working with MATLAB's appdesigner. It generates a binary file which is a zipped version of an XML containing the layout and another file containing the code.
Being a binary file, Git can't figure do diff and merge with it.
I've already checked out [Customize External Source Control to Use MATLAB for Diff and Merge](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/customize-external-source-control-to-use-matlab-for-comparison-and-merge.html) but I can't work out the details on how to do it on Mac OS with Git.

My git repo's config looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
            url = https://p_ackermann@bitbucket.org/mhealth_rwth/ma_pascal_ackermann.git
            fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    [branch "master"]
            remote = origin
            merge = refs/heads/master
    [diff]
        tool = MATLAB-Diff
    [difftool "MATLAB-Diff"]
            cmd = /Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64/mlDiff "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL"
    [merge]
        tool = MATLAB-Merge
    [mergetool "MATLAB-Merge"]
            cmd = /Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64/mlMerge "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
```

But `git diff someApp.mlapp` gives me:

> diff --git a/someApp.mlapp b/someApp.mlapp
>
> index 0ae9a33..18fe4e4 100644
>
> Binary files a/someApp.mlapp and b/someApp.mlapp differ

And trying to open the diff tool with `git difftool` gives me an alert window in MATLAB saying:

> File someApp.mlapp not found

I'm stuck here.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are jut using git wrong I believe. Because its a zipped file, you can not version control it. Git is for plain texts, if you compress it somehow, due to the complexity of the zipping algorithms, most of the bytes will change. There is no way to merge them. Either work in plaintext, or accept that everytime you change the zip you need to repush the whole thing. Note also that this will easily generate massive git repos, as you will be storing every version. In short: you are using version control wrong

Comment: @AnderBiguri, as I understand from [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/282860-will-app-designer-file-be-compatible-with-software-version-control-e-g-git-or-svn) MATLAB central thread using MATLAB's own diff and merge tools should indeed be able to handle this data. My problem is setting that up.

Comment: well, people suspect that it should work in that thread, no one actually says it does. But  what I can see from that is that they say "yeah, unzip and use version control"

Answer (score 0):

I did not find this easy. My solution is as follows;

in

```
%USER_HOME%/.gitconfig
```

add the lines

```
[diff]
    tool = matlab

[difftool "matlab"]
    cmd = "\"C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/mlDiff.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\""
```

Now, git diff should work as before. However,

```
$ git difftool fabulous.mlx
```

Should spin up matlab's diff tool...